# Any way to update/change deployed source code online via Google Cloud?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed source code via gcloud command line with no issue. However, I am currently away from my desktop and see a critical change to my app.yaml file that I would like to make.

Is this possible to do via my Google Cloud account?

Comment: which app.yaml's field would you like to update?

Comment: To an instance I defined

Comment: Do you mean the instance type? Also, is your app running on App Engine standard or Flex? Is it using automatic scaling, basic scaling or manual scaling?

Comment: Yes, Instance type. Forgive me, I'm in mobile. App is running on App Engine standard, with automatic scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [App Engine Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions/patch) to patch the specific version of your service and update the instance type since your app is using App Engine Standard. You can use the "Try this API" feature to update it right from your browser.

Comment: This is the answer. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help